# Move and remove Listbox item to another listbox using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want move list box item to another list box. I searched and found this location.

http://jsfiddle.net/bdMAF/1/

This is exactly I want. But I want to remove the list box items. Is it possible? Please help me as needful.

Thanks.

Comment: be specific about your requirement..!!
what are you asking ?

Comment: The demo you gave is working. What is it that you are looking for?

Answer (score 6):

I presume you mean remove them from the second list and back to the first list. Try this http://jsfiddle.net/bdMAF/38/

```
<div>
    <h3>List A</h3>
    <select id="list1" multiple="multiple" rows=2>
        <option value=1>Option 1</option>
        <option value=2>Option 2</option>
        <option value=3>Option 3</option>
        <option value=4>Option 4</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    <input id="button1" type="button" value="Move to List B" />
</div>
<div>
    <h3>List A</h3>
    <select id="list2" multiple="multiple" rows=2>        
    </select>
    <br/>
    <input id="button2" type="button" value="Move to List A" />
</div>

$(function(){
    $("#button1").click(function(){
        $("#list1 > option:selected").each(function(){
            $(this).remove().appendTo("#list2");
        });
    });

    $("#button2").click(function(){
        $("#list2 > option:selected").each(function(){
            $(this).remove().appendTo("#list1");
        });
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

why not add button2 and do like

```
$(function(){
    $("#button2").click(function(){
        $("#list1 > option:selected").each(function(){
            $(this).remove();
        });
    });
});​
```